# Run active project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is there a shortcut to run a project in my solution without setting it (set as startup project) and instead correlate it with the active file?

I mean run a project whose file is active, but I don't want it to be the default. It should be a different shortcut than <kbd>F10</kbd>, because I'm mainly talking about debugging!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could set this in the properties of the solution:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that's 4 clicks instead of 2.

Comment: **+1** The "Active Project" thing was bound to get me in trouble at some point.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a way to do exactly what you ask, but you can run any project:

- right-click the project in Solution Explorer
- Debug > Start new instance

It doesn't have to be the Start-up project.